# Why throwing a RuntimeException when my program could work normally by just skipping it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I was working on the databricks log analyzer app with spark and scala.
In the object ApacheAccessLog they throw a RuntimeException if the log line doesn't respect the set pattern.

```
log match {
  case PATTERN(ipAddress, clientIdentd, userId, dateTime, method, endpoint, protocol, responseCode, contentSize)
  => ApacheAccessLog(ipAddress, clientIdentd, userId, dateTime, method, endpoint, protocol, responseCode.toInt,
    contentSize.toLong)
  case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"""Cannot parse log line: $log""")
}
```

I would like that someone explain to me why i would throw a RuntimeException and break my program just because one log line doesn't respect my pattern? Isn't better to just skip that line so that the program will continue processing only the lines that respect the pattern?

Also i will be happy if you suggest a better idea as a workarround.

Comment: if you want to the program continue, you need to use try{YOUR CODE} catch{..} .

Answer (score 0):

Look, it's just an example, there is no philosophy in there :) You are right, more permissive solution would just skip that line, but sometimes you may want rather get an exception than miss something.

Why they wrote code that way? Maybe they expect every line match pattern, maybe something else, we will never know and it doesn't matter. But it is good that you think about the consequences of design decisions and alternative solutions